# How can I sort my column so that NaN is not shown?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, lambda

I tried sort_values to put na as last position. But it is not working. I do not wish to remove the NaN fields as it will affect my data analysis later.

```
def mortality_rate(row):
    if row['Population 2020 (in thousands)'] >= 50000:
        return row['Total Deaths'] / row['Total Infected']
   
df1['Mortality Rate'] = df1.apply(lambda row: mortality_rate(row), axis = 1)

df1 = df1.sort_values(['Smokers in Population (%)'],ascending=[False])

df1.sort_values(by = ['Mortality Rate'] , axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')

print(df1[['Country','Smokers in Population (%)', 'Mortality Rate']].head(10))
```

Current output

```
>                   Country  Smokers in Population (%)  Mortality Rate
>60              Montenegro                       45.9             NaN
>34                  Greece                       43.4             NaN
>39               Indonesia                       39.4        0.066014
>78                  Serbia                       38.9             NaN
>11  Bosnia and Herzegovina                       38.9             NaN
```

Desired output

```
>        Country  Smokers in Population (%)  Mortality Rate
>39    Indonesia                       39.4        0.066014
>30       France                       32.7        0.154892
>32      Germany                       30.6        0.045456
>89       Turkey                       27.2        0.027695
>17        China                       25.6        0.055173
```

The results should be filtered by descending 'Smokers in Population (%)' then 'Mortality Rate' for 'Country' with 'Population 2020 (in thousands)' > 50000. Currently the filter only applies to 'Smokers in Population (%)'. The 'Mortality Rate' values capture all population.

I cannot drop the rows in Mortality Rate as I need it for further analysis in the later part.

Comment: It seems that you forget the `df1 = ` before `df1.sort_values(by = ['Mortality Rate'] , axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')`

Comment: This will sort highest mortality rate first. The end result need to sort smokers in population first then mortality rate without NaN.